# How to loop through inventory and assign value in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I have a task in my Ansible playbook that I'm wanting iterate over each host in the group that I have and for each host I would like to assign a name from the hostname list that I've created in the vars folder.

I'm familiar with looping through inventory already by writing loop: "{{ groups['mygroup'] }}" and I have a list of hostnames I would like to assign each IP in 'mygroup' within the host file.

```
# In tasks file - roles/company/tasks/main.yml
- name: change hostname
  win_hostname:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ hostname }}"
  register: res

# In the Inventory file
[company]
10.0.10.128
10.0.10.166
10.0.10.200

# In vars - roles/company/vars/main.yml
hostname:
  - GL-WKS-18
  - GL-WKS-19
  - GL-WKS-20

# site.yml file located under /etc/ansible
- hosts: company
  roles:
    - common
    - company #This is where the loop exists mentioned above.

# Command to run playbook
ansible-playbook -i hosts company.yml
```

I seem to have the individual pieces down or know about it, but how can I combine iterating over hosts from an inventory group and assign names that I have in an already created list (in roles vars folder) already?

**UPDATE**
the task mentioned above has been updated to reflect changes mentioned in answer:

```
- name: change hostname
  win_hostname:
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: {{ groups.company|zip(hostname)|list }}"
  register: res
```

However the output I'm getting is incorrect, this should not run 9 times rather only three times, once per IP in the [company] group in the inventory. Also there are only three hostnames in a list that need to be assigned to each of the hosts in the inventory sheet.

```
changed: [10.0.10.128] => (item=[u'10.0.10.128', u'GL-WKS-18'])
changed: [10.0.10.166] => (item=[u'10.0.10.128', u'GL-WKS-18'])
changed: [10.0.10.200] => (item=[u'10.0.10.128', u'GL-WKS-18'])
changed: [10.0.10.128] => (item=[u'10.0.10.166', u'GL-WKS-19'])
changed: [10.0.10.166] => (item=[u'10.0.10.166', u'GL-WKS-19'])
changed: [10.0.10.200] => (item=[u'10.0.10.166', u'GL-WKS-19'])
ok: [10.0.10.128] => (item=[u'10.0.10.200', u'GL-WKS-20'])
ok: [10.0.10.166] => (item=[u'10.0.10.200', u'GL-WKS-20'])
ok: [10.0.10.200] => (item=[u'10.0.10.200', u'GL-WKS-20'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I have a question about looping in Ansible I also go visit the [Loops documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).  It sounds like you want to iterate over two lists in parallel, pairing an item from the list of hosts in your inventory with an item from the list of hostnames.  In previous versions of Ansible that would suggest using the `with_together` loop, while with more recent versions of Ansible that suggests the `zip` filter (there's an example in the docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together)).

To demonstrate this for your use case, I started with an inventory file that has three hosts:

```
[mygroup]
hostA ansible_host=localhost
hostB ansible_host=localhost
hostC ansible_host=localhost
```

And the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hostnames:
      - hostname01
      - hostname02
      - hostname03
  tasks:
    - name: change hostname
      debug:
        msg:
          win_hostname:
            name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.mygroup|zip(hostnames)|list }}"
```

Here I'm using a `debug` task instead of actually running the `win_hostname` task.  The output of running:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
```

Looks like:

```
TASK [change hostname] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'hostA', u'hostname01']) => {
    "msg": {
        "win_hostname": {
            "name": [
                "hostA", 
                "hostname01"
            ]
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'hostB', u'hostname02']) => {
    "msg": {
        "win_hostname": {
            "name": [
                "hostB", 
                "hostname02"
            ]
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'hostC', u'hostname03']) => {
    "msg": {
        "win_hostname": {
            "name": [
                "hostC", 
                "hostname03"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's paired each host from the inventory with a hostname from the `hostnames` list.

**Update**

Based on the additional information you've provided, I think what you
actually want is this:

```
    - name: change hostname
      win_hostname:
        name: "{{ hostnames[group.company.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

This will assign one value from `hostname` to each host in your
inventory.  We're looking up the position of the current
`inventory_hostname` in your group, and then using that to index into
the `hostnames` list.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Two lists to be looping together simultaneously. I did not know inventory groups are considered lists, I think that was one of my issues. Secondly, the looping with_x was very confusing and even looking at it had left me confused. Thank you going through this explanation!

Comment: After making the changes to loop and updating the name field's value to "{{ item.1 }} I am still getting some issues, the loop seems to run 9 times. The loop also assigned two of the hosts with the same same hostname. Why is this zip filter running 9 times?

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual data and tasks you're running? It's hard to figure out what might be going on otherwise. I'm assuming this example runs correctly for you?

Comment: I was able to successfully run and get the output you also showed, that is why i'm confused as to why i'm having the issue I am. The original question has been updated with output and setup.

Comment: You haven't shown the play itself, but I think I see what's happening.  What does the `hosts:` line look like on the play that is calling this task?

Comment: I believe the site.yml is the play you're asking for which I made an update/edit to my original question. the play calls the 'company' role and the hosts line for the play is: - hosts: company. I think i also may know what's going on here, when inventory sheet is iterating through the group, the task is iterating through each host all over again in the loop causing it to run 9 times. Even coming to this conclusion, I'm not sure how I would be able to address this.

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that might help.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! would just make a suggestion on changing the value of name in your suggestion to - "{{ hostnames[groups.company.index(inventory_hostname)] }}", the only changes that were made were group was changed to groups and a closing square bracket was added.

Comment: @larsks wouldn't this be super dangerous considering the fact that ansible had (have?) issues where the order of processing of the hosts in an host group would not be determined by the order in which they appear in the inventory? (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34861)