# Ansible: iterating and pairing inventory items with variables

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

This is directly related to the following link question, and the answer from [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks), that I tried, but it does not work: "[how to loop through inventory and assign value in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860671/how-to-loop-through-inventory-and-assign-value-in-ansible/)"

I was trying to do the same, and I tested to rename 2 VMs controlled by Ansible, but I get errors like the next one when I try to run the Playbook (`ansible-playbook -i hosts test_iterate_win.yml -vvv`), I would say that it is literally taking by name '**`System.Object[]`**' instead of, for example, **wCloud2**:

```
failed: [oldVM2] (item=[u'oldVM2', u'wCloud2']) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": [
        "oldVM2", 
        "wCloud2"
    ], 
    "msg": "Failed to rename computer to 'System.Object[]': Skip computer 'oldVM2' with new name 'System.Object[]' because the new name is not valid. The new computer name entered is not properly formatted. Standard names may contain letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), and hyphens (-), but no spaces or periods (.). The name may not consist entirely of digits, and may not be longer than 63 characters.", 
    "old_name": "oldVM2", 
    "reboot_required": false
}
```

In my inventory file:

```
[windows]
oldVM1 ansible_host=192.168.122.6
oldVM2 ansible_host=192.168.122.139
```

My Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hostnames:
      - wCloud1
      - wCloud2
  tasks:
    - name: change hostname
      win_hostname:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.windows|zip(hostnames)|list }}"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

I would say, you are making this super complex for yourself for nothing, when there could be a simple solution about it.

Your task could be easily resolved by just using [host variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables) in your inventory:

```
[windows]
oldVM1 ansible_host=192.168.122.6 newName=wCloud1
oldVM2 ansible_host=192.168.122.139 newName=wCloud2
```

Then your playbook is as easy as:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: change hostname
      win_hostname:
        name: "{{ newName }}"
```

---

Now, the reason why your attempt didn't work, is actually coming from a bit of a misconception you have on task(s) run on multiple hosts by Ansible, I would say.

Namely, when Ansible have a task (or a set of tasks) to run on multiple hosts, one and only one task need to be defined.

Based on the said task, when the inventory hosts is actually a group of hosts, the task will be run on the `host 1`, then the `host 2`, ... until the `host n`, before it goes to run the next task (if any).

*Nota:* still, don't take this for granted, there has been know issues where Ansible would not follow the order of definition of the hosts in the inventory (see: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34861), so really it could end up being `host 2`, `host n`, `host 1`.

Consider this playbook with the above inventory:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: change hostname
      debug:
        msg: '{{ newName }}'

    - name: another task
      debug:
        msg: 'some example'
```

The output of it will be

```
$ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [windows] *****************************************************************

TASK [change hostname] *********************************************************
ok: [oldVM1] => {
    "msg": "wCloud1"
}
ok: [oldVM2] => {
    "msg": "wCloud2"
}

TASK [another task] ************************************************************
ok: [oldVM1] => {
    "msg": "some example"
}
ok: [oldVM2] => {
    "msg": "some example"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
oldVM1                     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
oldVM2                     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Where you can clearly see that the first task (*named, change hostname*) is processed on all hosts before Ansible could move forward to other tasks in the play.

---

And really what your `System.Object[]` error means is that you are trying to feed an object (namely a list) in the `win_hostname` module's `name`, that tries to convert it as string somehow and fails badly, because, here is the list that your `item` variable contains:

```
[
    "oldVM1",
    "wCloud1"
]
```

Comment: that seems a brilliant solution, and a good philosophy ("keep it simple"), thanks a lot.
I will test it soon, and select your answer as accepted solution